# My data file is saved at a different final point every time I run it

Tags: fortran

I use Fortran 90 via Force 2.0, with a 64bits pc under windows 10.
Everytime I compile and execute my code one of my column (the 't' one at the left) that I write in a .dat file changes even though I didn't change my code.

```
! module
       module force_param
       implicit none
       integer,parameter :: dim=3
       integer,parameter :: dim_l=dim-1
       real*8,parameter :: rapmas=0.5, omega2=100, fsm2=1.E-4, x0_=0.1E0, x2_ =0.01E0
       real*8,parameter :: omeg=10.d0, Aex=0.01E0
       contains
       subroutine force(x,v,f)
       implicit none
       real*8 :: x(dim), v(dim), f(dim_l)
       f(1)=-omega2*(x(1)-x(3)) - omega2*rapmas*(x(1)-x(2))
       f(2)=-omega2*(x(2)-x(1)) - fsm2*(v(1)-v(3))
       end subroutine force
       end module force_param





      ! algorithme de heun

        subroutine heun(x,v,xn,vn,dt)
        use force_param
       IMPLICIT NONE
       real*8::x( dim),v( dim),xn(dim),vn( dim),dt
       real*8::f( dim_l), fn( dim_l)
       call force(x,v,f)
        xn(1: dim_l)=x( 1 : dim_l)+v( 1 : dim_l )*dt
        vn(1:dim_l)=v(1: dim_l)+f( 1 : dim_l )*dt
       call force(xn,vn,fn )
        xn( 1 : dim_l)=x(1:dim_l)+((v(1:dim_l)+vn(1:dim_l))*.5d0*dt)
        vn( 1 : dim_l)=v(1:dim_l)+((f(1:dim_l)+fn(1:dim_l))*.5d0*dt)
        end subroutine heun
```

Thank you, I don't know how to access the debugging options though, I tried the button that says 'debugging' but it doesn't seem to do anything. I initialized all my variables too and nothing changed :

```
      ! PROGRAM PRINCIPAL
      program vibrations
       use force_param
       implicit none
       integer,parameter :: n=50
       integer :: i
       real*8 :: dt,pi
       real*8:: x(dim),v(dim),xn(dim),vn(dim)
       real*8 :: t,tn
       pi=3.141592
       dt=2*pi/(omeg*n)
       x(1)=x0_
       x(2)=x2_
       x(3)=0
       v(:)=0
       xn(:)=0
       vn(:)=0
       t=0
       tn=0
       do i=0,n*1000
       t=i*dt
       x(3)=0
       v(3)=0
       tn=(i+n)*dt
       xn(3)=0
       vn(3)=0
       call heun(x,v,xn,vn,dt)


       open(11,file='oscill_libI.dat')
       write(11,*)t,xn(1), xn(2)
       x(:)=xn(:)
       v(:)=vn(:)
        enddo

      end program vibrations
```

Here is the beginning of my dat file, sometimes the 't' column goes from 0 to 62, sometimes from 0 to 79 it's like randomized, but the 2 right columns stay the same :

```
 0.0000000000000000       9.88551278186548116E-002  1.07106110228664085E-002
  1.25663681030273432E-002  9.54368715187558225E-002  1.28277973235651557E-002
  2.51327362060546865E-002  8.98431692414301264E-002  1.62639044499528901E-002
  3.76991043090820280E-002  8.22344006522621740E-002  2.08756113538187266E-002
  5.02654724121093729E-002  7.28284342737571672E-002  2.64687493992564297E-002
  6.28318405151367110E-002  6.18938950672803800E-002  3.28048473194145346E-002
  7.53982086181640559E-002  4.97418661274231927E-002  3.96091910096331989E-002
  8.79645767211914009E-002  3.67162863528836467E-002  4.65801381808427575E-002
  0.10053094482421875       2.31833471408859799E-002  5.33993871027770503E-002
  0.11309731292724609       9.52022271687244688E-003  5.97428674724096373E-002
  0.12566368103027342      -3.89651034653112948E-003  6.52919008503467374E-002
  0.13823004913330078      -1.67023992139428389E-002  6.97442687804509659E-002
  0.15079641723632811      -2.85562232108175044E-002  7.28248289506616686E-002
  0.16336278533935547      -3.91503348001675106E-002  7.42953335021119959E-002
  0.17592915344238280      -4.82199079113247164E-002  7.39631284187664967E-002
  0.18849552154541016      -5.55508033296286119E-002  7.16884480472895630E-002
```

Here is two example of the end of my .dat file, generated from the same code :

```
62.643344993591306      -2.22234174408908088E-002 -6.79345709753481353E-002
   62.655911361694336       7.81763163624332930E-004 -8.43500285728980836E-002
   62.668477729797360       2.31009413326696972E-002 -9.94182790176534326E-002
   62.681044097900390       4.40812444698733333E-002 -0.11254380214307025     
   62.693610466003413       6.31170757113199837E-002 -0.12318313084617104     
   62.706176834106444       7.96689081015940076E-002 -0.13086315388478151     
   62.718743202209467       9.32799461005491132E-002 -0.13519725211303918     
   62.731309570312497       0.10359012770409017      -0.13589874559045442     
   62.743875938415528       0.11034702522217735      -0.13279121399446445     
   62.756442306518551       0.11341330157177297      -0.12581535178107928     
   62.769008674621581       0.11277048866797904      -0.11503212942774470     
   62.781575042724604       0.10851897164177816      -0.10062214936426861     
   62.794141410827635       0.10087418344945331      -8.28812061224447061E-002
   62.806707778930658       9.01591351206557229E-002 -6.22121809658964242E-002
```

```
76.566880851745609      -2.17677700529351897E-002 -1.05802168534466483E-002
   76.579447219848632      -4.88389979588944381E-002  6.79397900452341150E-003
   76.592013587951655      -7.46968241174833236E-002  2.32872848719374026E-002
   76.604579956054678      -9.85925322542900023E-002  3.82250728574096491E-002
   76.617146324157716      -0.11983644140594378       5.09885339005944488E-002
   76.629712692260739      -0.13781930927178770       6.10355204755949760E-002
   76.642279060363762      -0.15203121044591339       6.79188940734381658E-002
   76.654845428466800      -0.16207729220063621       7.13017843304816629E-002
   76.667411796569823      -0.16768990946606288       7.09692653728316025E-002
   76.679978164672846      -0.16873675548102926       6.68360694761913066E-002
   76.692544532775869      -0.16522473162941959       5.89500848494855997E-002
   76.705110900878907      -0.15729943518448128       4.74915192035008926E-002
   76.717677268981930      -0.14524028276312445       3.27677494663660557E-002
   76.730243637084953      -0.12945142581913546       1.52040161357704148E-002
   76.742810005187991      -0.11044874807218197      -4.66974609003714767E-003
   76.755376373291014      -8.88433591287705327E-002 -2.62355258305883438E-002
```

```
! algorithme de heun

        subroutine heun(x,v,xn,vn,dt)
        use force_param
       IMPLICIT NONE
       real*8::x( dim),v( dim),xn(dim),vn( dim),dt
       real*8::f( dim_l), fn( dim_l)
       call force(x,v,f)
        xn(1: dim_l)=x( 1 : dim_l)+v( 1 : dim_l )*dt
        vn(1:dim_l)=v(1: dim_l)+f( 1 : dim_l )*dt
       call force(xn,vn,fn )
        xn( 1 : dim_l)=x(1:dim_l)+((v(1:dim_l)+vn(1:dim_l))*.5d0*dt)
        vn( 1 : dim_l)=v(1:dim_l)+((f(1:dim_l)+fn(1:dim_l))*.5d0*dt)
        end subroutine heun

      ! PROGRAM PRINCIPAL
      program vibrations
       use force_param
       implicit none
       integer,parameter :: n=50
       integer :: i
       real*8 :: dt,pi
       real*8:: x(dim),v(dim),xn(dim),vn(dim),f( dim_l),fn( dim_l)
       real*8 :: t,tn
       pi=3.141592
       dt=2*pi/(omeg*n)
       x(1)=x0_
       x(2)=x2_
       x(3)=0
       v(:)=0
       xn(:)=0
       vn(:)=0
       t=0
       tn=0
       f(:) = 0
       fn(:) = 0
       do i=0,n*1000
       t=i*dt
       x(3)=0
       v(3)=0
       tn=(i+n)*dt
       xn(3)=0
       vn(3)=0
       call heun(x,v,xn,vn,dt)


       open(11,file='oscill_lib.dat')
       write(11,'(f15.8,1x,f15.8,1x,f15.8)')t,xn(1), xn(2)
       x(:)=xn(:)
       v(:)=vn(:)
       enddo
       close(11)
      end program vibrations
```

Comment: You must show your full code, see [mcve]. Compile with al debugging options of your compiler. Try valgrind. Make sure all your variables and arrays are initialized.

Comment: Thanks you, I don't know how to access the debugging options though, I tried the button that says 'debugging' but it doesn't seem to do anything. I initialized all my variables (I edited the code in my original post) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you actually concerned about the whitespace? About which columns are occupied with your numbers? If you care about that, you cannot use `write(11,*)` you need to specify some explicit format. We have countless questions and answers about that.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean about whitespace, if it's about the white spaces in my program as long as it work I'm not concerned. I thought the columns occupied were decided by the order of the variables that are put after the write, as in if I code write(11,*)a,b,c I get a in the first column, b in the second etc.                   But I don't understand how changing the write format will help with my problem of randomized numbers. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: What randomized? What is randomized? What different output would you expect instead? Please note I get the exact same values every time I run your code. What did you mean by `62` or `79`?

Comment: Sorry I must not have been clear in my first post, I meant the last value of the left column. Basically every time I run my code, I go check the .dat file to see at what value the left column stop, and it's always (for me) a different number, 62 or 79 are example of these numbers. Maybe my compiler is faulty, I expect 50 (I may be wrong) or at least a number that doesn't change.

Comment: Where **exactly** is the 62 or 70 you are speaking about in the output you are showing?

Comment: I only showed the beginning of my file, but my problem is rather at the end of it (I realize that it wasn't smart of me to do it). I will put the end of two different files from the same code in my main code to show you

Comment: Ok I understand now, please see my answer. I got confused because some of your lines end at column number 79.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your issue: **You have to close your file.** Use `close(11)` before terminating your program. That way you make sure your output is saved fully.

And, as mentioned in the comments. You should open the file only once. Or close it and the open again for appending if necessary.

Comment: thank you, i will try this to see if it helps with my problem, is that the output you are getting from my code ? If so my problem really is with my compiler.

Comment: Yes, I am getting it from your file. But it is not a compiler problem. You are responsible for closing the file properly. Also, I am using a different operating system with a different file system.

Comment: Closing properly ? I always close the file between the different code runs.

Comment: There is no `close(11)` statement in your code. I am not talking about how you open it or close in your text editor. You must close it before ending your program.

Comment: Ok thanks ill try. Sorry I still have the same problem, my last value is still random.

Comment: You have to show how you updated your code. Be aware that you should not `open`  the file in each iteration. Use indentation in your code to make the structure visible.

Comment: Ok I will add that in my main post

Comment: oh my god thank you so much it was just the open that was in the wrong place